# Can I write and read messages from queue in beans described in one ejb-jar?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, message-driven-bean

I have two EJBs, which are described in one ejb-jar.xml.
The first one is stateless bean and puts a message in WebSpheres message queue with manually created connection.

```
@Remote({ Producer.class })
public class ProducerImpl implements Producer, Serializable {
  @Override
  public boolean send(ObjectNode json) {
    try {
        Connection connection = queueCF.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

        message.setText(json.toString());
        producer.send(message);
        return true;
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        sysLog.log(...);
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The second one is MDB and reads from that queue.

```
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {
  @Override
  public void onMessage (Message message) {
      try {
          sendToUrl((TextMessage)message);
      } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
          log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
      }
  }
}
```

The ejb-jar.xml looks like this (some env-entry stuff is omitted):

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>Producer</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.example.jms.ProducerImpl</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/queue</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>

        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/connectionFactory</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
    </session>
    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>Consumer</ejb-name>
        <mapped-name>jms/queue</mapped-name>
        <ejb-class>com.example.Consumer</ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationLookup</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>jms/lookup</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>

    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
```

The issue is that reading from queue exists in the same transaction as writing. Why do I think so? I just tried to call the Producer and it hadn't returned until the Consumer::onMessage had been finished.

I tried to mark Consumer::onMessage with different transaction propagation (NotSupported, RequiresNew, etc) and to make Consumer transaction type "Bean". But everything changed nothing.

So, the question is: can I read from queue within totally separate transaction, so that Producer wouldn't wait for Consumer?

Comment: The default CMT attribute for both EJBs is `REQUIRED`. The sending SLSB and the receiving MDB do not share the same transaction. The information you are providing is not sufficient for further analysis. Please reproduce the issue with a minimal(!) example and post the EJB code and configuration.

Comment: @Frito Maybe I don't understand what my problem is. How can I ensure that two actions are done in different transactions?

Comment: this is ensured by EJB spec.

Comment: @Frito :( 
Thank you. It means I must find solution in another place.
What should I do with the question?

Comment: Since you still have an issue, I recommend this: [stackoverflow - mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will probably find out more when doing so. If not, you have better information for asking here.